# mongodb ppa installs 3.2.9-rc0

Tags: mongodb

If I install (or upgrade) the community version from ubuntu using the ppa (deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse) I get version 3.2.9-rc0 which is just bad?  What gives?  Anyone else see the same?

Comment: I have the same issue, but as of Aug 8th it is still trying to get version 3.2.9-rc0. Don't know where it is getting and how to fix the issue. So any clue is appretiated.

Comment: It's working correctly for me.  Have you done an apt-get update before the apt-get upgrade?

Comment: And if you already have the rc version installed, you will have to install the older version with something like apt-get install mongodb-org=3.2.8 and do the same for all of the mongodb pkgs.

Answer (score 3):

If you were unlucky to get apt-get update while mongo packages list still contained 3.2.9-rc0 release reference, the apt-get will whine about packages missing until the next release (and refuse to upgrade other packages without --fix-missing option).

I found no easy native way to force apt-get to refetch and update packages list (apt-get clean doesn't help), it seems the only option is to do something like

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*mongo*
```

After that apt-get update / upgrade combination should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be fixed today:

sudo apt-cache policy mongodb-org
mongodb-org:
  Installed: 3.2.5
  Candidate: 3.2.8
  Version table:
     3.2.8 0
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
     3.2.7 0
        500 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
...